# Calculate area of this figure

Tags: trigonometry

I have an homework assignment where I have to calculate area of the figure underneath.

[image: figure]

I used the following formula to calculate the result $\frac {130 \cdot 55 \cdot sin35}{2} = 4188 m$ and then $A = 1787 + 3954 = 5975 m$

I divided the figure into two triangels. And then calculated the distance between the a and b. I used Law of sines for that.

I wonder is this the correct result?

Thanks!!

Comment: Looks wrong to me. Can you explain your calculation in more detail?

Comment: In particular, where did you get the 130 in your calculation? Where did you get the 35? That quotient certainly does not equal 4188 (unless, maybe, your calculator is set to radians). Where did you get 1787, and where did you get 3954? And how on Earth did you get $1787+3954=5975$?

Comment: I measured the area in Geogebra and got $\approx 6293m^2$, so your answer is incorrect. Also, your image depicts the quadrilateral as having all four angles less than $180^\circ$. This is not true....

Comment: @DavidH Yes the figure is not ideal. Are you sure about 6293? I made it around 6614.63 with a quick calculation.

Comment: @S4M1R The law of sines? What did you get for the distance ab?

Comment: The distance ab = 130 by me calculation

Comment: @almagest I'm not sure about $A=6293$, but I am pretty sure $6275<A<6300$ provide hard upper and lower bounds. So you could say I'm sure that $A=6293\pm18$. Do you have an uncertainty range on your value?

Comment: @S4M1R That must be wrong because then the triangle would have sides 190,55,130! Two sides with sum shorter than the third side.

Comment: When I use the Law of Cosines to solve for ab, I obtain $c = \sqrt{190^2 + 55^2 - 2(190)(55)\cos(20^\circ)} \approx 139.59$ units.

Comment: An easier way to do it is to drop perpendiculars from the other two vertices onto the long side length 190. Then you have to calculate the areas of three right-angled triangles and a rectangle.

Comment: $6293$ looks right, I get
$$\begin{align}
A &= (190-55\cos(20^\circ) - 70\cos(75^\circ))\frac{55\sin(20^\circ) + 70\sin(75^\circ)}{2}\\
&\quad + \frac12 55^2\sin(20^\circ)\cos(20^\circ) + \frac12 70^2\sin(75^\circ)\cos(75^\circ)\\
&\approx 6292.787199872313
\end{align}$$